A good and simple way to set the connection string depending on whether we are testing the application or pushing it to production
I was tasked with upgrading the application version from .net core 2.0 to .net 8, since I'm doing it for the first time, I had to fix the code a bit. I noticed that in my company the connection string is set to a fixed value and when the "Publish" option is used, the programmer must change the connection string to the production database before this operation and after uploading the changes, he changes the database name to the test database and uploads the changes to GIT so that the rest of the programmers work on the test database. The test and production databases are on the same server, the only difference is the database name (we work on our internal server).
I was tasked with changing this and I read a bit about the different versions of the appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Production.json files.
I need advice on how to approach this, I mean how to set it up so that depending on whether we are working locally on the application or the application is uploaded to production, the system itself knows which connection string to use.
We use our own DbContext and in the OnConfiguring method I prepared two appsettings files depending on whether it is a development or production environment, in each of these files I entered a connection string, while the appsettings.json file itself I set empty.
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Production.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
       .AddEnvironmentVariables()
       .Build();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("XXXXX");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
}

I need a little help whether I am going in the right direction.

The default way shown in the docs already works. You don't need any of that code. Just use AddDbContext in Program.cs with a connection string loaded from builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("XXX"). DON'T put any configuration code in the DbContext itself

The correct solution is to use environments for this. Publishing itself should use publishing profiles in which you can set an extra flag /p:EnvironmentName:Production SO link for reference. Depending on the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable that your app is running with, it should pick the correct appsettings - if they are added to the configuration builder (which they seem to be).

@nbokmans .NET already takes the environment into consideration.

Besides that, don't configure your appsettings in the OnConfiguring of your DbContext... this should be done in application startup.

@PanagiotisKanavos you can still publish using different profiles or publish to a different 'target environment' e.g. staging, acceptance, whatever you might have. So I think it's imperative to look at publish profiles being used and make sure they contain the correct environment names.

.NET Core already allows using multiple environments based on the value of the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable (for web apps) or DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT for other apps

@nbokmans you don't need publish profiles for this, you can add more settings files and load them based on conditions like the OS or env variables. I used different settings files for Windows and Linux in the past, by checking the Environment.OSVersion setting and using appsettings.{OS}.....json as a template, to load extra settings with .AddJsonFile

@nbokmans the answers to that link mix up publish profiles with environment variables and publishing to IIS. If you publish to IIS you may need a transform for the final web.config file, but you can also use conditions in your .csproj to copy different config files to the publish folder..
